# How to delete multiple rows from beantablemodel in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I want to delete multiple rows at a times on selection.

Here is my code:

```
            int[] indexList = queryTable.getSelectedRows();
            queryTableModel.removeRows(indexList);
            queryTable.clearSelection();
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(queryTable);
```

Please help.

Comment: Please show your TableModel inplementation... Why `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(queryTable)`?

Comment: Don't use SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(). The is not need to use that method. The TableModel will notify the table when data has changed so the table can repaint itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple example of removing selected rows from model:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        final JTable t = new JTable(model = new DefaultTableModel(0,1));
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
            model.addRow(new Object[]{i});
        }
        JButton removeSelected = new JButton("remove");
        removeSelected.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[] selectedRows = t.getSelectedRows();
                for(int i=selectedRows.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
                    model.removeRow(selectedRows[i]);;
                }
            }
        });
        add(new JScrollPane(t));
        add(removeSelected,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: @MandarPandit hm, I think 3 line of code in `actionPerformed()` needn't to be explained, that's clear.

Comment: +1 for deleting from the end of the TableModel, not the start.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) as table model, this should be enough:

```
int[] viewIndexes = table.table.getSelectedRows();
for(int i = viewIndexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    int modelIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewIndexes[i]);
    ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelIndex);
}
```

Never forget to convert the selected indexes from ***view*** to ***model***. Otherwise you'll have problems if your table is sorted.

If you are using a custom [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), the process is almost the same, there won't be great differences.

In addition, you don't have to do nothing to update the ***view*** after adding/deleting/updating data, the ***model*** will notify the ***view*** in such events and this last one will be updated accordingly.

See [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial for further details.

Comment: This will not work. When you remove the first row all the other rows are shifted down by one so the indexs of the selected rows is no longer correct. You need to remove the rows from the end of the TableModel.

Comment: Thanks, the point was about converting view index to its respective model index and I've totally overlooked that @camickr

Answer (score 2):

> How to delete multiple rows from beantablemodel in java?

There is no BeanTableModel in Java.

If you happen to be referring to this [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) then you can use the `removeRows(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Selected rows by the user
int selectedRows[] = table.getSelectedRows();

if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
    // Every time a row is removed, the array will fill the empty gap moving 1 position all 
    // items that come after the removed item, so the next position to remove will be 
    // index + 1, then +2, +3, etc...
    int compensation = 0;

    // Removes row from selected index and compensates the misalignment
    for (int row : selectedRows) {
        model.removeRow(row - compensation++);
    }
}
```